# Meteor MongoDB not returning all object properties in array on document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using MeteorJS, I have a MongoDB collection where each document has an address field that is an array of objects. Here's how it looks in the db:

```
{
  "_id" : "eEzHuNCHPPGNLo2mp",
  "addresses" : [
    {
      "type" : "Dropoff",
      "street" : "123 MAIN ST",
      "street2" : "",
      "city" : "ANYTOWN",
      "state" : "ST",
      "zip" : "12345-6789",
      "country" : "US",
      "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -100.100100,
          30.303030
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I go to the command line and try `db.contacts.find({_id: 'eEzHuNCHPPGNLo2mp' },{ 'addresses': 1 });` I get that exact output.

Here's how I would find the same document via Meteor's Mongo implementation:

```
    var docs = Docs.find(
                  { '_id': 'eEzHuNCHPPGNLo2mp' },
                  { fields: { 'addresses': 1 } }
                ).fetch();
```

When I do that though, the document comes back as:

```
[{
  type: 'Dropoff',
  street: '123 MAIN ST',
  city: 'ANYTOWN',
  state: 'ST',
  zip: '12345-6789',
  country: 'US'
}]
```

Both the `street2` and `loc` properties have been dropped.

Even if I ask for each property specifically, it will not return them.

Any ideas?

Comment: that's odd. what happens if you do the find() w/o the 2nd argument? i.e. just the filter.

Comment: have you tried using findOne?

Comment: Are you executing `Doc.find()` on the client or server?  If it's the client, check your server publication to see if you by chance have excluded the `addresses.street2` and 'addresses.loc` fields.  This could result in not seeing them on the client.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback.

@zim: w/o 2nd argument I still get the truncated results from the `addresses` array, but the other fields show up fine.

@mutdmour: Tried findOne and no luck, same results

@jordanwillis: This is on the server, so I should have access to everything. When I remove the projection, all of the other fields on this collection come through as expected, just not `addresses`.

Any other ideas?